# insert data with association in sequalize not work?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

**hdr.hasMany(line,{foreignKey: 'hdr_uuid', sourceKey: 'uuid'})**

**line.belongsTo(hdr,{foreignKey: 'hdr_uuid', targetKey: 'uuid'})**

> hdr.create(
>   { "name":"ch", "line":[{ "num":"01" },{ "num":"02" }]
>   },{include:[line]})

i insert data using sequalize with nested object.it is not working?
my problem was data not inserted in line.only insert hdr table

```
{ "name":"ch", 
  "line":[
 { "num":"01" },
 { "num":"02" }
]}
```

hdr and line definition in below attached image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVV9s.png)

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. What is wrong? What error are you receiving?

Comment: hasMany, belongsTo  use for insert data but it is not insert data in line table . it is only insert hdr table

Comment: Please add the code you are using to insert that data. Also include the code used to create both of the tables.

Comment: Hi please i have attached image.please give a solution from my problem

Comment: hdr.create( { "name":"ch", "line":[{ "num":"01" },{ "num":"02" }] },{include:[line]})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed `sourcekey` and `targetkey` and added an alias name. It works fine

```
hdr.hasMany(line,{foreignKey: 'hdr_uuid',as:'line'})

line.belongsTo(hdr,{foreignKey: 'hdr_uuid',as:'hdr'})

hdr.create( { "name":"ch", "line":[{ "num":"01" },{ "num":"02" }] },{include:[{model:line,as:'line'}]})
```